# Error passing a list to a SASS mixin: "] expected"

Tags: css, sass, postcss, scss-mixins, stylelint

I'm passing a list to a SASS mixin and it works (no error in the browser or console) but my editor (VS Code) says there are errors.
The code is:

```
  @include gridAuto(
    320px, 
    [
      ['sm', 2],
      ['', 1],
      ['lg', 3],
    ],
    var(--space-xl), 
    var(--space-xxl)
  );
```

I get errors on this line `['sm', 2],`. The errors:

```
] expected
] expected
) expected
at-rule or selector expected
```

These are the styles dependencies the starter theme is using:

```
"autoprefixer": "^9.4",
"css-loader": "^0.28.9",
"cssnano": "~4.0.5",
"node-sass": "~4.9.4",
"postcss-custom-properties": "^9.1.1",
"postcss-loader": "~2.1.0",
"postcss-safe-parser": "~3.0",
"sass-loader": "~6.0",
"style-loader": "^0.22.1",
"stylelint": "^8.4.0",
"stylelint-config-standard": "~18.2.0",
"stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.5",
```

I attach a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the SCSS validator built into VS Code is struggling to understand this construct. As you are using the stylelint extension for VS Code, [you can turn off the built-in validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#optional-but-recommended-setup) by adding the following to your user settings:

```
"scss.validate": false
```

(The stylelint extension itself doesn't have a problem with this construct.)